QFiledDialog setFileMode(Directory) with nameFilters
In a python program using Qt I would like to be able to select a directory using QtWidgets.QFileDialog() with Directory mode of setFileMode() method, but also filter the contents of the selected directory using the setNameFilter() method. I'm currently using:
    def select_dir(self):
        """
        Opens a file dialog for source file path selection.
        """
        dlg = QtWidgets.QFileDialog()
        dlg.setFileMode(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.Directory)
        dlg.setNameFilter(("Any files (*);;text files (*.txt);;csv files (*.csv)"))
        if dlg.exec():
            dir = dlg.selectedFiles()[0]
            fileTypeSelection = dlg.selectedNameFilter()
    return fileTypeSelection, dlg.selectedFiles()[0]

But this is not allowing for selection of the filetype filter in the dialog window (the drop-down is not visible) on Windows OS. Can Directory mode be combined with name filters or mime filters?

Sorry but I don't understand. Qt normally tries to use the native file dialog, it normally shows both files and directories (as the docs explain): for the non native file dialog and for most native ones (but on Linux it may depend on the desktop manager and configuration) with the exception of Windows (which only shows directories). I assume that you're on a system that also shows files, so: 1. are you asking for a way to only show files that match that specific filter? 2. do you want to filter out dirs that don't contain those files?

No, I want to select a directory (don't care if the OS shows files too) but capture the user-desired file-type to filter directory contents with. ie only *.txt files within C:\myDir. If this is not possible with QFileDialog I can do something else, but would be tidier to capture the file type filter in the dialog.

So, you just want the user to select a directory and then a file type filter. The simplest solution would be to just show a further dialog when the first is closed, asking the user to select a specific file filter.

That's right. Your suggestion is not bad, just additional UX load.

I completely agree. The only alternative is to use the non native dialog with setOption(), which will look less "natural" to the users, but may still be acceptable.

I'll look into setOptions(). Thanks!

If you use a non-native dialog, you can quite easily add custom widgets and/or modify the existing widgets. The QFileDialog ui file can be found in the source code, so you can open it in Qt Designer to see the structure.

@musicamante, QFileDialog.setOption(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog, True)
and then
QFileDialog.setNameFilter()
did the trick. Did you want to submit an answer?

Why not answer your own question? Anyway, it's not recommended to abuse the name filter. (Bad UX)
